# Google sheets function compare two value's not working

Tags: google-sheets

I made a function for Google sheets. I have two question:

- The function works but it's slow, can someone tweak the function?
- There is a bug that if I compare two values, and one value is e.g. 8 and the other 11 it doens't work. It seems that if the values have different numbers e.g. 8 = 1 number, 88 = 2 numbers, 888 = 3 numbers, the compare doesn't work. If the two values has the same numbers it works correct, e.g. 88 and 44. If I compare with a function in the sheet itself, it works. Anyone an idea, how to fix this?

The function:
It needs to compare a value in column x (cmcprice) with a value in a different column (entry, exit1, exit2, exit3, exit4 and stop). The compare is on the same row. If the value in cmcprice is higher then entry, exit1 - 4 or lower then stop, the function needs to write a date in a different cell (other column, same row). If there is already a date in the cell, it needs te skip. Because the cmcprice changes every x time, I check every x time, if the value is higer or lower.

Thanks,
Pieter

```
function CompareRow() {

  var s1=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Trades %");
  var lr=s1.getLastRow()
  // 1. Retrieve values from the sheet
  var cmcprice = s1.getRange(2,21,lr-1,1).getValues();
  var entry  = s1.getRange(2,3,lr-1,1).getValues();
  var exit1  = s1.getRange(2,6,lr-1,1).getValues();
  var exit2  = s1.getRange(2,9,lr-1,1).getValues();
  var exit3  = s1.getRange(2,12,lr-1,1).getValues();
  var exit4  = s1.getRange(2,15,lr-1,1).getValues();
  var stop  = s1.getRange(2,18,lr-1,1).getValues();
  var nu = new Date();

  for (var i = 0; i < lr; i++) {
    if(cmcprice[i]>entry[i]){
        if(s1.getRange([i+2],5).getValue()==""){
        s1.getRange([i+2],5).setValue(nu);
        }
    }
    if(cmcprice[i]>exit1[i]){
        if(s1.getRange([i+2],8).getValue()==""){
        s1.getRange([i+2],8).setValue(nu);
        }
    }
    if(cmcprice[i]>exit2[i]){
        if((s1.getRange([i+2],11).getValue()=="") && (exit2[i]!="")){
        s1.getRange([i+2],11).setValue(nu);
        }
    }
    if(cmcprice[i]>exit3[i]){
        if((s1.getRange([i+2],14).getValue()=="") && (exit3[i]!="")){
        s1.getRange([i+2],14).setValue(nu);
        }
    }
    if(cmcprice[i]>exit4[i]){
        if((s1.getRange([i+2],17).getValue()=="")  && (exit4[i]!="")){
        s1.getRange([i+2],17).setValue(nu);
        }
    }
    if(cmcprice[i]<stop[i]){
        if(s1.getRange([i+2],20).getValue()==""){
        s1.getRange([i+2],20).setValue(nu);
        }
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Hi there. You could improve the performance of the function if you didn't use so many calls to SpreadsheetApp inside the for loop. You could get the complete arrays with `getValues`, modify them and once you have the desired values, write them in the `sheet` with `setValues`, applying the same `range`. On the other hand, the error when comparing numbers with different digits is strange. You could try debugging and assigning the values to a variable before the comparison to see its value and check that nothing out of the expected happens.

Comment: To give you more detailed help, it would be helpful if you could share the `sheet` to get a more comprehensive view of the problem.